# how to apply body.addClass("className") to iframe from the parent document

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I have a [WP page](https://vision.scientific-tools.org/visime-360/availability-of-ophthalmic-surgeons/) with embedded iframes. There is a widhet that changes the style of the page, and I need that it also changes the style of all embedded iframes. The style changes by clicking the button that has the following event handler:

```
NightVersionButton.click(function (event) {
    // this is a part that changes the page style (and it works)
    event.preventDefault();
    Cookies.set('contrast', 'night', { expires: 7, path: window.cookiePath });
    body.removeClass('highcontrast highcontrast2 highcontrast3');
    body.addClass('night');
    
    // this is a part that should change the style of all iframes, but it does not work due to the error "Uncaught TypeError: single_iframe.contentDocument.body.addClass is not a function"
    var all_iframes = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe');
    for (let single_iframe of all_iframes) {
        var iframe_doc = single_iframe.contentWindow ? single_iframe.contentWindow.document : single_iframe.contentDocument;
        iframe_doc.body.addClass('night');
        //$(single_iframe).contents().find('body').addClass('night'); // this jQuery alternative does not work neither
    }

});
```

However, the part of the JS code responsible for changing the styles in all iframes does not work, with the console error "Uncaught TypeError: single_iframe.contentDocument.body.addClass is not a function".

Please could you suggest the correct solution on how to change the JS that it will also apply addClass to all iframes?

Comment: There is no addClass in DOM, that is a jQuery method. There is classList.add

Comment: Thanks a lot! Changing the string to `iframe_doc.body.classList.add('night');` works, but in this case the error 'Uncaught DOMException: Permission denied to access property "document" on cross-origin object' appears, even if both parent document and iframe are situated in the same domain!

Comment: Well you can not alter 3rd party domains. [Same Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy)

Comment: The parent document and iframe are situated at the same (my own) domain